# Tensor product of direct sums = direct sum of tensor products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

I have an example in my mind for which this statement holds, but I'm wondering if this is true in general:

> Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be right $R$-modules, and let $N$ be a left $R$-module. Is it true that $(M_1 \oplus M_2) \otimes_R N$ is isomorphic to $(M_1 \otimes_R N) \oplus (M_2 \otimes_R N)$?

In particular I'm not seeing how the map $\phi: (m_1, m_2) \otimes_R n \mapsto (m_1 \otimes_R n, m_2 \otimes_R n)$ is injective. In another word, if $(m_1 \otimes_R n, m_2 \otimes_R n) =(0,0)$ then why is $(m_1, m_2)\otimes_R n = 0$?

**Edit:** This is true for vector spaces because $m \otimes_F n = 0$ if and only if either $m=0$ or $n=0$. This needs not be true if $F$ is not a field.

**Edit:** I feel like this is true if $M_1, M_2$, and $N$ are free abelian groups since then they'll have bases.

Answer (score 4):

This is true in general. In case you know some category theory, a short proof would be to use that since $\otimes_R M$ is left adjoint to $\hom(M,-)$, it preserves colimits.

Usually explicit constructions of a tensor product are *ugly*, it's better to use its universal property whenever possible. From this universal property is that you've constructed the map $(M_1 \oplus M_2) \otimes_R N \to (M_1 \otimes_R N) \oplus (M_2\otimes_R N)$.

Note that tensoring the inclusions $\iota_i \colon M_i \hookrightarrow M_1 \oplus M_2$ with $N$ give maps $\iota_i \otimes 1 \colon M_i \otimes_R N \to (M_1 \oplus M_2) \otimes_R N$, which in turn induce a map

$$
(\iota_1 \otimes 1, \iota_2\otimes 1) \colon (M_1 \otimes_R N) \oplus (M_2\otimes_R N) \to (M_1 \oplus M_2) \otimes_R N.
$$

Explicitly, a pair of elementary tensors $(m\otimes n, m'\otimes n')$ has image $(m,0)\otimes n+(0,m') \otimes n'$.

Check that this is the inverse of your map by computing both compositions.

Comment: Can you get the second map from the universal property of tensor products as well? i.e. the map $(m\bigotimes n, m'\bigotimes n')\mapsto (m, 0)\bigotimes n + (0,m')\bigotimes n'$

Comment: Indeed, if $f \colon A \to B$ is a linear map, one shows that $f \otimes 1 \colon A \otimes N \to B \otimes N$ exists via the universal property (checking that $(a,n) \mapsto (f(a),n)$ is bilinear $R$-balanced). From this you know that $\iota_i \otimes 1$ are well defined. And then you use the universal property of the direct sum. Strictly speaking we can't use the universal property of the tensor product to construct the map 'at once' because the domain is not a tensor product (although we're about to prove that it is, up to isomorphism)

Comment: But is the map well defined? In general elements in $M_1\bigotimes_R M_2$ can be written non-uniquely as $\mathbb{Z}$ linear combination of $m_1\bigotimes m_2$. The fact that you defined the map using elementary tensors seem to suggest the necessity of the existence of a basis for $M_i\bigotimes_R N$, which happens only if $M_i$ and $N$ are free abelian groups.

Comment: I did not define the map on elementary tensors; I defined a bilinear $R$-balanced map which induces a map from the tensor product, and we know the values it takes in elementary tensors.

Answer (score 0):

$\renewcommand{\braket}[1]{\left\langle  #1 \right\rangle}$
We write $\braket{m_i}:=(\ldots,0,m_i,0,\ldots)\in \bigoplus_i M_i$ for a element whose $i$ th component is $m_i$, and the others are $0$ in general.

The universality says there is a map

$$\iota_i \otimes 1 \colon M_i \otimes_R N \to (M_1\oplus M_2) \otimes_R N; (m_i\otimes n)_i\mapsto (\braket{m_i})_i\otimes n,$$

which is the map tensored the inclusions $\iota_i \colon M_i \hookrightarrow M_1\oplus M_2$ with identity $1:N\to N$.

Since $\iota_i \otimes 1$ is a $R$ linear map, it takes $0$ to $0$

i.e. $$m_i\otimes n=0\implies (\braket{m_i})_i\otimes n=0.$$

So, if $m_i\otimes n=0$ for all $i$, we have

$$(m_1, m_2)\otimes n=((m_1, 0)+(0, m_2))\otimes n=(m_1, 0)\otimes n+(0, m_2)\otimes n=0.$$